# PostgreSQL return second 'Group' as an array

Tags: postgresql, array

I have some tables that include websites and visitors and I am trying to write a query that produces a 'top 10' for each site, the tables look something like this...

```
websites
-------
website_id (pk)
url
description

visitors
-------
visitor_id (pk)
ip_address

website_visits
--------
visit_id (pk)
website_id (fk)
visitor_id (fk)
visit_date
visit_duration
```

I know that I can use two GROUP BY 's to produce a single list ordered by website using the query below...

```
SELECT w.website_id, v.visitor_id, count(wv.visit_id)
FROM website_visits ws, websites w, visitors v
WHERE wv.website_id = w.website_id and wv.visitor_id = v.visitor_id
GROUP BY w.website_id, v.visitor_id
ORDER BY w.website_id ASC, count(wv.visit_id) DESC
```

But I would like to improve this by a) only showing the top ten for each site, and b) grouping each top 10 result into an array, so that the results look something like this:

```
website_id    top_ten
432           [{visitor_id:354,visits:958},{visitor_id:987,visits:971}...etc]
325           [{visitor_id:456,visits:955},{visitor_id:1056,visits:465}...etc]
```

(I have used JSON here but it could be in any format)

I have experimented with using the SELECT ARRAY(...) function in a subquery but I cannot seem to get it working and I am not sure if thats the correct approach?

Can someone advise? Thanks

Using PostgreSQL 9.0 by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
with ranked_visits as (
  SELECT w.website_id, 
         v.visitor_id, 
         count(wv.visit_id) as visits,
         row_number() over (partition by w.website_id order by count(wv.visit_id) desc) as rnk
  FROM website_visits wv
    JOIN websites w ON wv.website_id = w.website_id
    JOIN visitors v ON wv.visitor_id = v.visitor_id
  GROUP BY w.website_id, v.visitor_id
  ORDER BY w.website_id ASC, count(wv.visit_id) DESC
)
select website_id, string_agg('visitor_id: '||visitor_id||',visits:'||visits, ', ')
from ranked_visits
where rnk <= 10
group by website_id;
```